# "Throw dice again" method for a Yahtzee program

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, validation

I am trying to have a method that takes the a five-dice random roll (int [] dice) and allows the user to say which dice they want to throw again (1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th , or 5th die) like in the game Yahtzee. I also have to validate that the user picked a number between 1 and 5, that they don't put a duplicate number, and that they don't enter more than 4 numbers to roll again. If the requirements aren't satisfied, I need to out print "Illegal die!" and ask the user to enter again. Whichever die/ dice they choose needs to be randomized again and be assigned to the dice[] array. This is what I have so far that basically takes the user string input and changes it to integers and I can't figure out how to do the other things I mentioned above. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
 public static void throwAgain(int[] dice) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("List which die to throw again: ");
    String line = keyboard.nextLine();
    String [] strArray = line.split(" ");
    int [] intArray = new int[strArray.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++){
        intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(strArray[i]);  // Changes user's string input to an array of integers
    }

    // Arrays.sort(intArray);

}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. In the future, please try not to cram six different questions in one, and make each question specific, explaining what about the situation is confusing/problematic. This looks like homework; our goal for homework questions is to make you learn, not to do it for you. You will get much more specific answers if you ask a specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also have to validate that the user picked a number between 1 and 5

Check each int as you are looping. `>` and `<` are useful.

> that they don't put a duplicate number

Make a subloop that will check each previous value. `=` is useful.

> and that they don't enter more than 4 numbers to roll again.

`.length` and `>` are useful.

> If the requirements aren't satisfied, I need to out print "Illegal die!"

Have a boolean flag `error` that starts out as `false` and set it to `true` when a validation check fails. At the end, check the flag. `System.out.println` is useful.

> and ask the user to enter again.

`while` is useful. Set `error` as true at the top, and `false` as the loop starts. Loop while there is an error.

> Whichever die/ dice they choose needs to be randomized again and be assigned to the dice[] array

Loop over the `intArray`, and assign new random values to the `dice` elements whose indices are one less than each element of `intArray`. `[]`, `-` and `java.util.Random` are useful.